# Checkboxes are not checked in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I have list of object to show for checkboxes

```
public weeks = [
{ value: 'All', display: 'All',isChecked: false },
{ value: 'Mon', display: 'Mon',isChecked: false },
{ value: 'Tue', display: 'Tue',isChecked: false },
{ value: 'Wed', display: 'Wed',isChecked: false },
{ value: 'Thu', display: 'Thu',isChecked: false },
{ value: 'Fri', display: 'Fri',isChecked: false }
];
```

app.component.html

```
      <span *ngFor="let week of weeks">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="weeks" [(ngModel)]="week.isChecked" class="week" >
          {{week.display}}
        </label>
      </span>
```

Issue is that it now bind selected checkboxes  .

app.component.ts

```
this.weeks.forEach((month) => {
    var i = this.selected_weeks.indexOf(month.week);
    if(i != -1) {
      week.isChecked = true;
      console.log(week.isChecked);
    }
  });
```

in component it mark that object true but in view it not selected

Comment: Try adding `<div>{{months | json }}</div>` and check if the values really change. If they do, please provide more information where the code `this.weeks.forEach()` is being called from

Comment: I have the feeling it's a scoping issue. I suggest using another for loop as you lose the scope `this` within the forEach loop.
`for (let i=0; i<this.weeks.length; i++) { 
   // do everything inside here
}`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes here it marked checked

Comment: meanz in in data its property is true but not bind

Comment: You are iterating over `months` and binding the checkbox to `months`, but then updating the `weeks`. Why do you expect the checkboxes to update?

Comment: no no its weeks......

Comment: Where "its weeks". Your HTML only uses `months`

Comment: basically there are two fields , i copy paste code mistake... question updated

Comment: updated you can see now :)

Comment: You didn't answer yet where your above code is being called from

Comment: weeks array in app.component.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Still no information about where the code is called from